# How to present an Alert after being redirected from an Ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my success event I want to redirect to a new page. No problem, got that. However, after being redirected to the new page I want to present a alert. I thought I could do it by using  `document.referrer` function however this is not working for me. One problem could be that the refering page has an id at the end of the url, hence why I put the star there. But I have tried it without the star as well.  What am I doing wrong ? What is the best way of achieving this ? TKS !

The sending page has this Ajax call. This works great.

```
$.ajax({
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            type: "POST",
            url: 'save_edit/'+$id,
            data: formData,
            success:function(){
                location.href = "http://mysite/open_quotes"
            },

            error:function(){
              alert('there has been a system level error - please contact support')

            }

        });
```

The Receiving page has this little script at the bottom. This doesn't work:

```
    function referedPage() {
    var x = document.referrer;  
    if (x =="http://mysite/quote_edit/*"){
     alert('Success');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting some data in local storage

```
localStorage['alert'] = 'true';
location.href = "http://mysite/open_quotes"
```

```
if (localStorage['alert'] == 'true'){
    localStorage.removeItem('alert')
    alert('Success');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you should do something like this:

```
        url: 'save_edit/'+$id+'?back='+document.location,
```

add a back variable through an url parameter, so you can assure from where you  call.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Ajax. Where do I put the url: ? Inside the Ajax call ?

Comment: Exactly,  

once you done that $.ajax({jsonobject}) there is an json object inside as a parameter.  

and it has the following properties on it  > **headers,   
type,url,data,success, error **  
url is the property responsible to hold the url to call.  
so in your case, just concatenate  
url: 'save_edit/'+$id+'?back=http://mysite/open_quotes'   
and it will work properlly.  <br/>

and in the next page just get the ""back"" parameter. which would have your url